# Can we set a gravity for part of the textview

Tags: android, textview

I have a text like this "If the bot is unresponsive, do you want system to restart it? How bot works"

I am trying to make it appear like this in two lines

```
If the bot is unresponsive, do you want system
to restart it?                   How bot works
```

I browsed through and I found this piece of code

```
spannablecontent.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(
                        Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_OPPOSITE),
                        0, 15,
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

But this is only working if the text "How bot works" is in separate line. If it is in same line, it is coming right after "restart it?" without any space.

Kindly assist me with this issue.

Comment: Can't you use two separate TextView?

Comment: @Amy It can be achieved through two textviews. I am trying to achieve through spannable because I have these kind of requirements throughout the app.

Comment: Basically you want to have space between two words irrespective of the words are in single line or multiple lines?

Comment: @Amy that's one aspect. Plus making one of the group of works clickable. So in this case, I want to make "How bot works" clickable. And I have implemented the clickable span